# Using xrandr to scale screen along Y

Tags: centos, xrandr

Im trying to configure my screen to occupy the upper half of a single monitor such that the entire desktop is still displayed. The following command successfully shows only the upper half of the screen:

```
xrandr --fb 1920x540 --output VGA1 (1080 vertical resolution)
```

I would expect the following command to then scale the screen while still occupying only the upper portion of the monitor.

```
xrandr --fb 1920x540 --output VGA1 --scale 1x.5
```

However, this ends up scaling the display and occupying the entire monitor.

EDIT: I have a stretched LCD panel where the manufacturer literally "cuts" the display such that the vertical resolution it reports is greater than what's visible. Rather than adapt my software to fit a particular resolution I thought it would be interesting to scale the entire desktop, which would also allow for ease of system management.

EDIT: I've tried several monitors (using VGA) with no change. I've also tried adding new modes with half the vertical resolution, with and without halving the refresh rate.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do, but you could look at `--scale-from` instead.

Comment: I tried `--scale-from`, but it appears equivalent to the second command listed in my question.